# How Can I download Hex file output of IAR compiler to MCU by using ULink

Tags: iar, keil

Ulink programmer is used with keil compiler to flash arm based cpus. Keil creates .axf object file  as an output. But I am using IAR compiler in my project and it creates different output file. How can I flash my MCU with IAR compiler output by using Ulink programmer?

Regards

Comment: IAR can generate additional output formats, Intel hex format for example. Check the project settings for possible alternatives and check if ULink supports any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, It's NOT possible. ULINK2 is supported only by Keil µVision - none other. If you decide to work exlusive with IAR, you should buy a J-link. Visit below link for more details:
http://www.keil.com/forum/24905/
Although there are some other approach for program an ARM microcontroller such as Flash Magic and etc.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11110879)

Comment: You're right Dmitry. But in this link don't mentioned why ULINK don't support IAR output. I think that's because of file types that Keil can create as output and IAR can't.